# VB Stopping a button from being clicked, but allow it to be hovered over

Tags: vb.net, events, button

I'm currently generating a form with enough buttons in certain places to form words. I place some letters in the right place, and make them red, and lock them in place (with `btn(x).enabled = false`), and the rest of the letters are randomised.

[Example of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igqps.jpg)

When any button is clicked, it gets sent to one Sub, and a it does a process. As I don't want the buttons which already have the right letter in (and are red) to start this process, which is why I disable the buttons. But I now need ALL buttons (including the disabled ones) to be able to be hovered over.

So my question is this, is there a way of making buttons non-clickable, but still be able to hover over them and return a result?

Currently using:

```
AddHandler Btn(x).Click, AddressOf HandleDynamicButtonClick
AddHandler Btn(x).MouseHover, AddressOf HandleDynamicButtonMouseHover
```

Comment: There is also a RemoveHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HandleDynamicButtonClick code put the code you dont want to execute in an If statement like this

```
If Button1.BackColor <> Color.Red Then
    'execute this if the backcolour isnt red
End If
```